# Splitting a text file into 2 equal halves

Tags: linux, bash, file, split, directory

I want to split all the text files in a directory into 2 equal halves for each file. I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
d=2
for file in /home/user1/Documents/files/*.txt; do

l=$(wc -l < "$file")    #was l= wc $file | awk {'print $1'}

echo $l

sp=$((l/d))    #was sp = $((l/d))

echo $sp

split -l $sp $file $file.

done
```

Comment: Remove the space on the line where you assign "split". Also. consider renaming the variable `split` as `lines` so it doesn't get confused with the command `split`.

Comment: Also, have a think about files with odd numbers of lines, and what happens when you divide by 2 - you may need to add 1 to make sure you don't get 3 "halves"   :-)

Comment: changed split to sp but the division doesn't work.

Comment: Did you remove the space after the =  ?

Comment: Please post your updated code so we can see what you have so far.

Comment: the current code looks like as in the question. I edited it.

Comment: You still have a space in "sp=SPACE$((l/d))"

Comment: And the line "l=wc $file" looks nothing like what @Mansuro suggested for you.

Comment: That worked. removed the spaces in sp= $((l/d)) and l= wc $file | awk {'print $1'} changed to l=$(wc -l < "$file")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
l= wc $file | awk {'print $1'}
```

should be

```
l=$(wc -l < "$file")
```

Comment: No, it should not have spaces either side of the equals sign and it would be better as `l=$(wc -l < "$file")`

Comment: The awk is unneeded too... because `wc` will not print the filename, or the word and character counts if you invoke it like I suggested.

Comment: `l` will, however, contain the leading whitespace produced by `wc -l < "$file"`, which shouldn't be a problem, rather just something to keep in mind.